# Is it possible to have an AIX virtual machine running on Windows?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, aix

A couple of years ago I was told this is not possible, well... actually i didn't understand why.

As time goes by, so are days off our lives, is it still impossible? Or now there are some solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AIX runs on PowerPC processors. It does not run on x86 or x86_64.

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) emulates enough of PowerPC to run PPC Linux, but still it is a long way to AIX or OS X.

Comment: as per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) AIX supports ROMP, IBM POWER, PowerPC, x86 (IBM PS/2), System/370, ESA/390 so the x86 version obviously can run on an x86 hypervisor like virtualbox or vmware...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The PS/2 version is Aix 1.xx which is so ancient it isn't funny anymore. It is similar to try running Windows v1.0 in a VM. Yes, it can be done, but not for any useful purpose. It isn't even useful to learn about Aix as current Aix versions (6 and later) are very different. I learned Aix on V3 and V4. I recently had to work on a Aix 7 system and had to dig through a lot of documentation to understand the differences. I would be far worse coming from an even older Aix version.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve had success with the following configuration:

- macOS 10.12.3
- virtual box version : 5.1.16
- aix version : 1.3
- Windows 10 , 8 , 7 , xp with virtual box 5.1.16 tested : all success

See below:

[image]

reference site : https://sites.google.com/site/rhdisk0/unix/aix/aixps2

Comment: Good job! Thx sharing

Comment: Ah https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX#IBM_PS.2F2_series I didn't know there was an (older) AIX port for x86

Comment: only x86 version can run in a hypervisor. Other versions can't run on x86 (obviously) and must be run through an emulator